# Twitter API : build query

Tags: twitter, operator-keyword

I'm working on a module which uses Twitter API.

For my tests, I want to retrieve tweets :

```
    - Containing #uber
    - OR
    - From a certain user
    - No retweets
    - max 50 tweets
    - since last id
```

My actual query is :

```
?q=%23uber%20Exclude%3Aretweets+OR+from%3AROUGEmemoire%20Exclude%3Aretweets&count=50&since_id=619498059077156865
```

Nevertheless, I do not retrieve data from ROUGEmemoire, only from #uber.

If I inverse the query like that :

```
q=from%3AROUGEmemoire%20Exclude%3Aretweets+OR+%23uber%20Exclude%3Aretweets&count=50&since_id=619498059077156865
```

I retrieve data only from ROUGEmemoire.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you simply try `#uber OR @ROUGEmemoire` as your query? Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't want at+ROUGEmemoire which will return all of tweets referencing at+ROUGEmemoire. I want tweet from this account. I solved my problem by doing two request. I tested it, my daemon have retrieve all of the expected data. Thanks though :)

Comment: You are welcome! And you are completely right of course.